# "The Hateful Eight" - Full of hate or hated?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Tarantino's new movie "The Hateful Eight" is translated to "Os Oito Odiados" which can be translated to "The Hated Eight".

Is this a correct translation of the title? Doesn't the title actually mean that these eight people are full of hatred and not actually hated?

Answer (score 1):

**The Hateful Eight** does mean the eight are full of **hatred** though in the movie they do seem to be the **hated eight** since the are all refugees from the storm and outcasts.

*Oito Odiados* seems to translate to Hateful Eight in Portugese [here](https://translate.google.com/#pt/en/odiosa%20oito)

Comment: Your answer really doesn't state what *hated* means, as you are only referencing characters (refugees) we don't know. Just being *refugees* doesn't explain why they are "hated".

Comment: They are **outcasts**

Comment: Are you saying *outcasts* by definition are hated (as a language question)? But if it is in the context of this movie, it should be stated as such.